# How to add conditions in Q objects search

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

how do i filter my objects if user entered product_length 10 than my objects should return length is greater than equal to 10 for example i am using Q objects to filter out my data.

in my `views.py`

```
def search(request):
    query=request.GET.get("q").lower()

    post = CreateIndustrialPost.objects.filter(
        Q(product_length__icontains=query,admin_approval=True,user_remove_post=False)
       ).values()
```

in this it returns all data i want to filter as above mention.

here is my `models.py`

```
class CreateIndustrialPost(models.Model):
    product_length = models.IntegerField(max_length=1000,blank=True)
    user_remove_post = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin_approval = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

for example what i want is if user search product_length = 10
than i want to show result in which product_length be should greater than 10 or equal to 10.

Comment: I am not really following what you want to do here. Can you share your model(s) and give an example that makes it clear what you aim to achieve?

Comment: Hello @WillemVanOnsem i have  edited my question

Comment: @AMITTIWARI `product_length` should be an `IntegerField` if it is meant to store integers...

Comment: @AMITTIWARI: how do you ask the user for a `product_length`? Through some form I suppose?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes im using form

Comment: @AMITTIWARI: but then that form has two fields? One for `q` and another field (unknown name) for the product length?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes

Comment: hello @WillemVanOnsem thanks for your time i got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `gte` which means greater than or equal. Like this:

```
def search(request):
    query=request.GET.get("q").lower() # query = 10 for example

    post = CreateIndustrialPost.objects.filter(
        Q(product_length__gte=query, admin_approval=True, user_remove_post=False)
    ).values()
```